# dividing input value from result

Tags: javascript

What I want is if I click button2, result of button1 divides value3 to be printed. I tried many times and  tried to search similar cases in here but I couldn't find. I need your help.

follow is the code snippets:

```js
$(function () {
            $('#calculating').on('click', function () {
                $('#purchnmb').removeAttr('hidden');
                $('#gohome').removeAttr('hidden');
                $('#calculating').attr('hidden', true);
            });

            $('#gohome').on('click', function () {
                $('#gohome').attr('hidden', true);
                $('#purchnmb').attr('hidden', true);
                $('#calculating').removeAttr('hidden');
            });
        });

const cal = () => {
            const A = parseInt(value1.value.replace(/,/g, '')),
                B = parseInt(value2.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
            // console.log(parseInt(A), parseInt(B));
            const res = A * 0.7 * parseFloat(100 / B);

            result.innerText = `your price is  ${new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'EUR',
            }).format(res)}.`;
        };
```

```html
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

<h3 class="first">total</h3>
            <input type="text" id="value1"/>dollars

            <h4 class="second">discount</h4>
            <input type="text" id="value2"/>%
            
            <h5 class="third">price</h5>
            <input type="text" id="value3"/>dollars

<div class="calculate">
            <button class="calculator" id="calculating" value="button" onclick="cal()">button1
            </button>
            <button id="purchnmb" value="new tab" hidden>button2
            </button>
            <button id="gohome" value="new tab" onclick="history.go(0);" hidden>home</button>
            <h6 class="result-value" id="result"></h6>
```

Comment: Its very unclear what you are trying to do. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: if i press button1, value1 and 2 calculation is printed. and now i want that if i press button2, it print me the result that button1's result dividing value3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more options to get the result of button1

1. Store the result into global variable
2. Create a calculation function that return the result

I am using the second option. So when you hit the button1 and button2, it will recalculate them.

The reason why I prefer using the second option is that I consider you will change the value that used on the first result(button1) before hitting the button2

```js
$(function () {
    $('#calculating').on('click', function () {
        $('#purchnmb').removeAttr('hidden');
        $('#gohome').removeAttr('hidden');
        $('#calculating').attr('hidden', true);
    });

    $('#gohome').on('click', function () {
        $('#gohome').attr('hidden', true);
        $('#purchnmb').attr('hidden', true);
        $('#calculating').removeAttr('hidden');
    });
});

function printResult(val) {
  result.innerText = `your price is  ${new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'EUR',
  }).format(val)}.`;
}
        
const res1 = () => {
  const A = parseInt(value1.value.replace(/,/g, '')),
        B = parseInt(value2.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  return A * 0.7 * parseFloat(100 / B);
}

const cal2 = () => {
  const res = res1();
  const price = parseInt(value3.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  const total = res/price;
  printResult(total)
}

const cal = () => {
    printResult(res1())
};
```

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<h3 class="first">total</h3>
<input type="text" id="value1"/>dollars

<h4 class="second">discount</h4>
<input type="text" id="value2"/>%

<h5 class="third">price</h5>
<input type="text" id="value3"/>dollars

<div class="calculate">
  <button class="calculator" id="calculating" value="button" onclick="cal()">button1
  </button>
  <button id="purchnmb" value="new tab" hidden onclick="cal2()">button2
  </button>
  <button id="gohome" value="new tab" onclick="history.go(0);" hidden>home</button>
  <h6 class="result-value" id="result"></h6>
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you. Would it be possible to remove decimal number of button2's result?

Comment: possible, it depends on you if you want to remove the decimal with parsing it to integer or round them up / down